# Trouble using enum in a set c++

Tags: c++, stl, enums, set, switch-statement

I put all my enums into a set.  I am trying to iterate through the set and use a switch statement to give variables values(haven't done that yet).  I am having trouble setting up an iterator to put in the switch statement that will tell me which enum I am using.  Here is my code.  The *it is giving me a null value.

```
    for(std::set<CreateAndUseIniFile::iniFileValues>::iterator it=m_modules.begin(); it!=m_modules.end(); ++it)
{
    switch(*it)
    {
    case CreateAndUseIniFile::VOLTAGE1_OFFSET:
        break;
    case CreateAndUseIniFile::VOLTAGE12_OFFSET:
        break;
    case CreateAndUseIniFile::VOLTAGE123_OFFSET:
        break;
     }
}
```

Here is the code where I added to the set

```
    m_modules.insert(CreateAndUseIniFile::VOLTAGE1_OFFSET);
m_modules.insert(CreateAndUseIniFile::VOLTAGE12_OFFSET);
m_modules.insert(CreateAndUseIniFile::VOLTAGE123_OFFSET);
```

Here is the enum

```
class CreateAndUseIniFile {
 public:

enum iniFileValues
{
    VOLTAGE1_OFFSET,
    VOLTAGE12_OFFSET,
    VOLTAGE123_OFFSET
    }
  std::set<CreateAndUseIniFile::iniFileValues> m_modules;
};
```

Comment: In C++11 you'd prefer using an enum class instead of this enum inside your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your container should be:

```
std::set< CreateAndUseIniFile::iniFileValues>
```

and iterator

```
std::set< CreateAndUseIniFile::iniFileValues>::iterator it;
```

And it will work as expected.

Note: switch may be optimazed, so you will not be able to step into until you add something more to switch cases, for instance:

```
for ( std::set< CreateAndUseIniFile::iniFileValues>::iterator it = s.begin(); 
                                               it != s.end(); ++it) {
    switch (*it) {
        case CreateAndUseIniFile::VOLTAGE1_OFFSET:
        {
            int iu = 100;
            break;
        }
        case CreateAndUseIniFile::VOLTAGE12_OFFSET:
        {
            int u = 1000;
            break;
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I made those changes and I am still getting nothing for the value

Comment: @Aaron add something to switch cases

Comment: Thanks, enums are a little tricky for me to work with, but when I have to come back to code 6 months later is so much easier to make changed.